# id3 show picture in mfc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to write a program that can edit MP3 tag.
And this program is using MFC SDI.
But,now,I encountered a problem.
I have completed everything I want using c++ Win32 Console Application.
But I don't know how to show my MP3 cover picture in picture control with MFC,

This is my code in win32:

```
char* imagefile = "Cover.jpg";
ID3_Tag currentTag;
currentTag.Link("song.mp3",ID3TT_ID3V1 | ID3TT_LYRICS3V2 | ID3TT_MUSICMATCH);
ID3_Frame currentFrame;
currentFrame.SetID(ID3FID_PICTURE);
currentFrame.GetField(ID3FN_MIMETYPE)->Set("image/jpeg");
currentFrame.GetField(ID3FN_PICTURETYPE)->Set(11);
currentFrame.GetField(ID3FN_DATA)->FromFile(imagefile);
currentTag.AddFrame(currentFrame);
currentTag.Update();
```

So,can anybody teach me how to show picture when I use MFC Picture Control??
Or,does anybody have other ways to do the same thing?
Sorry,I'm new to MFC.And My English is not very well~
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you will want to extract the image from the id3 tag in memory, then show it. What you do is you use id3lib's API to extract the binary image data (it's been too long that I worked with it, I don't know how to do it), then decode the image using CBitmap (look up the functions in MSDN) and then use a CStatic and its SetBitmap() function to set the bitmap to display in the control. Now, most likely CStatic won't display it in the way you want it, because CStatic is very limited. Then what you need to do is write your own control in which you override OnPaint(), there get a DC and BitBlt or StretchBlt from the CBitmap into the DC. Look on codeproject.com for examples on how to show images and how to make custom controls - it's way too much code to just bang out in a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SHLoadImageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416681.aspx) to load the jpeg file. The function will return the HBITMAP structure that can be passed to your picture control. I assume you use CStatic for it. In this case just call

```
m_stPicture.SetBitmap(SHLoadImageFile(imagefile));
```